# AttributeError: 'SentenceTransformer' object has no attribute 'embed_documents'

Tags: langchain, sentence-transformers, faiss

I have loaded locally my SentenceTransformer model and I am able to embed my sample sentences.

```
embed_model = SentenceTransformer('all-MiniLM-L6-v2/')
embeddings = embed_model.encode(sentences)
```

I also have created my documents using LangChain RecursiveCharacterTextSplitter.

```
text_splitter = RecursiveCharacterTextSplitter(
    chunk_size = 1000, # the character length of the chunk
    chunk_overlap = 100, # the character length of the overlap between chunks
    length_function = len, # the length function - in this case, character length (aka the python len() fn.)
)

combined_documents = text_splitter.transform_documents(test_data)
```

Now, I want to create my VectorStore using LangChain FAISS over my documents, and I am getting this error.

```
vector_store = FAISS.from_documents(combined_documents, embed_model)

---------------------------------------------------------------------------
AttributeError                            Traceback (most recent call last)
Cell In[28], line 16
      7 embed_model_id = 'sentence-transformers/all-MiniLM-L6-v2'
      9 #core_embeddings_model = HuggingFaceEmbeddings(cache_folder = 'all-MiniLM-L6-v2/')
     10 #)
     11 
     12 #embedder = CacheBackedEmbeddings.from_bytes_store(
     13 #    embed_model, store, namespace=embed_model_id
     14 #)
---> 16 vector_store = FAISS.from_documents(combined_documents, embed_model)

File ~/train_efficientdet/LLM/langchain-master/libs/langchain/langchain/schema/vectorstore.py:420, in VectorStore.from_documents(cls, documents, embedding, **kwargs)
    418 texts = [d.page_content for d in documents]
    419 metadatas = [d.metadata for d in documents]
--> 420 return cls.from_texts(texts, embedding, metadatas=metadatas, **kwargs)

File ~/train_efficientdet/LLM/langchain-master/libs/langchain/langchain/vectorstores/faiss.py:602, in FAISS.from_texts(cls, texts, embedding, metadatas, ids, **kwargs)
    575 @classmethod
    576 def from_texts(
    577     cls,
   (...)
    582     **kwargs: Any,
    583 ) -> FAISS:
    584     """Construct FAISS wrapper from raw documents.
    585 
    586     This is a user friendly interface that:
   (...)
    600             faiss = FAISS.from_texts(texts, embeddings)
    601     """
--> 602     embeddings = embedding.embed_documents(texts)
    603     return cls.__from(
    604         texts,
    605         embeddings,
   (...)
    609         **kwargs,
    610     )

File /opt/conda/lib/python3.10/site-packages/torch/nn/modules/module.py:1614, in Module.__getattr__(self, name)
   1612     if name in modules:
   1613         return modules[name]
-> 1614 raise AttributeError("'{}' object has no attribute '{}'".format(
   1615     type(self).__name__, name))

AttributeError: 'SentenceTransformer' object has no attribute 'embed_documents'
```

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

You can try below code

```
    from transformers import AutoTokenizer, AutoModel
    import faiss  

    # Load the model and tokenizer
    model_name = "your local model"
    tokenizer = AutoTokenizer.from_pretrained(model_name)
    model = AutoModel.from_pretrained(model_name)

    # Set pad token
    if not tokenizer.pad_token:
        tokenizer.pad_token = tokenizer.eos_token

    # Load documents
    raw_documents = "your documents"

    # Split documents
    text_splitter = RecursiveCharacterTextSplitter(chunk_size=1000, chunk_overlap=0)
    documents = text_splitter.split_documents(raw_documents)

    # Create embeddings using the model and tokenizer
    inputs = tokenizer(documents, return_tensors="pt", padding=True, truncation=True)
    with torch.no_grad():
        embeddings = model(**inputs).last_hidden_state.mean(dim=1).numpy()

    dimension = embeddings.shape[1]
    index = faiss.IndexFlatL2(dimension)  
    index.add(embeddings)
```